# qt : change qcontextmenu trigger

Tags: qt, contextmenu

Normally, when mouse right button is clicked, it causes QContextMenuEvent. But is it possible to change the button? I mean that I want to use mouse left button with "ALT" modifier. I'm trying to access THAT in mousePressEvent, but it doesn't work in right way.

Comment: Please show how do you try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by subclassing QWidget:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};
```

And its implementation:

```
MyWidget:: MyWidget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMenu menu;
    QAction *act1 = menu.addAction("action1");
    QAction *act2 = menu.addAction("action2");
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton&&
            event->modifiers()&Qt::AltModifier){

        QAction *selectedAction = menu.exec(event->globalPos());
        if(selectedAction == act1)
        {
            //do something
        }else if( selectedAction == act2 ){
            //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it related to "mouseReleaseEvent". I followed your suggestion, and it solved some problems. I use this solution on QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItem, and I want to NOT select the item when I show up the menu.